# Beaglebone black (BBB) rev C 3.8.13-38-ARCH SPI doesn't work, Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: beagleboneblack, spi, archlinux-arm

I have troubles with enabling SPI on BBB, ofc followed [tutorial from the hipstercircuits.com.](http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-spi-with-device-tree-on-beaglebone-black-copy-paste/) 
I even installed a fresh arch linux to the uSD in case I really messed up system on eMMC.

My settings are:

Since SPI1 has issues with HDMI I disabled anything HDMI related I found.
Not sure about fdfile entry though, found it somewhere on the web. (I also tried without it)
Currently I'm working on the SD card if that matters.

uEnv.txt

```
optargs=quiet coherent_pool=1M fdtfile=am335x-boneblack.dtb capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

I took dts file straight from the hipstercircuits.com and compiled it with alarm/dtc-overlay 1.4.1-1 installed via pacman.

After disabling HDMI in uEnv.txt

```
[root@alarm ~]# echo BB-SPI1-01 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
```

went ok and I saw:

```
[root@alarm ~]# cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots
 0: 54:PF---
 1: 55:PF---
 2: 56:PF---
 3: 57:PF---
 4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
 5: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
 6: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
 7: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-SPI1-01
```

I also tried echoing BB-SPIDEV0, BB-SPIDEV1 and BB-SPIDEV1A1 found here:

```
 [root@alarm spi_a]# ls -l /lib/firmware | grep SPI
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1351 Jan 29 17:04 BB-SPI1-01-00A0.dtbo
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1185 Jan 25 01:06 BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dtbo
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1185 Jan 25 01:06 BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1185 Jan 25 01:06 BB-SPIDEV1A1-00A0.dtbo
```

Result of the spidev_test is always the same.

What is more interesting I didn't see anything about P9_29, P9_31 etc, which are part of SPI1, in pingroups:

```
[root@alarm ~]# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pingroups
registered pin groups:
group: pinmux_userled_pins
pin 21 (44e10854)
pin 22 (44e10858)
pin 23 (44e1085c)
pin 24 (44e10860)

group: pinmux_rstctl_pins
pin 20 (44e10850)

group: pinmux_i2c0_pins
pin 98 (44e10988)
pin 99 (44e1098c)

group: pinmux_i2c2_pins
pin 94 (44e10978)
pin 95 (44e1097c)

group: pinmux_mmc1_pins
pin 88 (44e10960)

group: pinmux_emmc2_pins
pin 32 (44e10880)
pin 33 (44e10884)
pin 0 (44e10800)
pin 1 (44e10804)
pin 2 (44e10808)
pin 3 (44e1080c)
pin 4 (44e10810)
pin 5 (44e10814)
pin 6 (44e10818)
pin 7 (44e1081c)

group: pinmux_userled_pins
pin 21 (44e10854)
pin 22 (44e10858)
pin 23 (44e1085c)
pin 24 (44e10860)
```

The spidevs are present in /dev

```
[root@alarm ~]# ls -l /dev | grep spi
crw------- 1 root root 153,   1 Jan 29 17:13 spidev1.0
crw------- 1 root root 153,   0 Jan 29 17:13 spidev1.1
```

To test the interface both python method mentioned in the tutorial and spidev_test.c ([spidev_test.c](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c)) compiled on the BBB were used.

```
[root@alarm ~]# gcc spidev_test.c -o spidev_test
```

In case of python library there is no error but also nothing at the output - not even a clock signal on the SCL line.

spidev_test returns:

```
[root@alarm spi_a]# ./spidev_test
can't set spi mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Aborted (core dumped)
[root@alarm spi_a]# ./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev1.0
can't set spi mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Aborted (core dumped)
[root@alarm spi_a]# ./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev1.1
can't set spi mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I have to make use of *.dts and *.dtb files provided at the beginning of the hipstercircuit's tutorial?

I probably screwed up sth easy. Any ideas what was it?
Did you get it working just like that?
All advices are welcome and will be very appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used this .dts and worked fine (both spidev1.0 and spidev1.1 on the spidev_test.c). There are some more lines than in the  [linux documentation](http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Enable_SPIDEV#SPI1_D0_Output_and_D1_Input) which allow to enable second chip select for being used by SPI1 and properly configure the GPIO on the pin 42.

You should see now the spi pin muxing correctly.

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2013 CircuitCo
*
* Virtual cape for SPI1 on connector pins P9.29 P9.31 P9.30 P9.28
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
* published by the Free Software Foundation.
*/
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

/* identification */
part-number = "BB-SPI1-01";
version = "00A0";

/* state the resources this cape uses */
exclusive-use =
    /* the pin header uses */
    "P9.31",    /* spi1_sclk */
    "P9.29",    /* spi1_d0 */
    "P9.30",    /* spi1_d1 */
    "P9.28",    /* spi1_cs0 */
        "P9.42",    /* spi1_cs1 */
    /* the hardware ip uses */
    "spi1";

fragment@0 {
    target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
    __overlay__ {
        /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
        bb_spi1_pins: pinmux_bb_spi1_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x190 0x33  /* mcasp0_aclkx.spi1_sclk,  INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                0x194 0x33  /* mcasp0_fsx.spi1_d0,      INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                0x198 0x13  /* mcasp0_axr0.spi1_d1,     OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                0x19c 0x13  /* mcasp0_ahclkr.spi1_cs0,      OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
                0x164 0x12  /* eCAP0_in_PWM0_out.spi1_cs1   OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                0x1A0 0x32  /* Other P42 pin, INPUT_PULLUP */
            >;
        };
    };
};

fragment@1 {
    target = <&spi1>;   /* spi1 is numbered correctly */
    __overlay__ {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&bb_spi1_pins>;

        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        spi1_0{
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            compatible = "spidev";

            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
        };


        spi1_1{
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            compatible = "spidev";

            reg = <1>;
            spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;
        };
    };
};};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the ioctl.h.

When I search for 'iotl.h', the result is as follows,

```
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/ioctl.h
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/hdlc/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/mmc/ioctl.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctl.h
```

So there is no corresponding sys/ioctl.h
I am trying to find the correct ioctl.h